# Stop Canvas Image from Moving on Resize

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I use `drawImage(...)` to draw a jpeg onto a HTML5 canvas but when I zoom in or out (using Ctrl+ / Ctrl-) the image moves around. I feel like I am overlooking something blindingly obvious, is this the case?

I will also include the code I am using to draw the image:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.save();
ctx.arc( x, y,r, 0, Math.PI * 2 );
ctx.clip();
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
ctx.restore();
ctx.closePath();
```

Comment: What do you meaning with "the image moves around"?

Comment: The image will move around because the canvas is being zoomed into / out of. What do you expect it to do? Sit still?